# How To Draw Smooth Line Chart With SVG?

Tags: svg, charts, uibezierpath

I'm working on a data visualization project that I need to show some info on a line chart. So I've used SVG to draw the lines but I need to use curves and make a smooth chart. How can I achieve this in SVG.

This is what I've done so far: 
[Current Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaDAK.png)

And this is what I want to do:
[Desired Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp41p.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a curve-fitting routine that will turn your points into Bézier curves.

A good starting point is the curve-fitter by Philip J. Schneider from the Graphic Gems book.

Go to https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/FitCurves.c for the code.